# Autofac - Basic Explanation of Setting up Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

So I'm trying to set up Autofac into my own ASP.Net web-project.  I've modified existing ASP.Net projects that have dependency injection already set up, so I'd like to learn how to set up a project from scratch.  I asked a friend on how to do this, and he gave me code.

This is absolutely fantastic, because I know it will work.  However, it sucks because - also with the tutorial I found on the Autofac website - it doesn't explain much (I'm much more of a pictures-detail guy, I hate word problems.  Have to visualize it!)

So, here is this code that works.

```
// Create your builder.
1 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
2 builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

3 builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
4 builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
5 builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
6 builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

// assign interfaces here to the container so that it knows how to resolve requests
7  builder.RegisterType<foo>().As<ifoo>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

// create container
8 var container = builder.Build();
9 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Could someone explain to me - command by command - what each step does?  I know what dependency injection does.... a central source creates/distributes Interfaces for use in controllers and models, without the need of said controllers/models creating each instance themselves.  But it'd be nice to understand how the backbone works.

Here's what I have so far:

**1)** Create a list of instructions, let's say a recipe you follow step-by-step

**2)** Add to recipe 'recognize the web-app controllers' so that you can call a controller as needed.  E.g, FooController needs something from BarController, resolve BarController

**3) - 6)** No idea

**7)** Put on the recipe to add the Interface 'ifoo' to the mix; it's lifetime exists on every request.  Do not hold any longer than that; send out a new one for each action basically

**8)** Finalize recipe instructions.  Actually follow instructions and put the results into a giant bowl.

**9)** Tell the application where this giant bowl of goodies exists.  Except when you grab something from the bowl, it's actually a copy of what was put in.  Thus, endless supply of goodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3) This extension method is similar to RegisterControllers - it registers all model binders from given assembly. Model binders are classes that implements IModelBinder interface. Their purpose is to map data incoming from request to model that controller action accepts. For more information you may see example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

4) RegisterModelBinderProvider registers AutofacModelBinderProvider - thanks to it your model binders registered with RegisterModelBinders will be automatically applied for your application.

5) RegisterModule registers autofac module - a class that derives from Module class. Typically within it you override Load method in which you may store additional autofac registration stuff. AutofacWebTypesModule code may be found here: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc3/AutofacWebTypesModule.cs?r=94f70ab10f4d65991c600e2e80171ce4847589e6
It registers classes that wraps HttpContext.Current. As HttpContext is static it cannot be mocked in unit tests and thus is problematic to be automatically tested. AutofacWebTypesModule helps you overcome that issue.

6) RegisterSource allows you to register new Sources. They work very similarly to service lookup pattern. Thanks to them you can resolve certain things that were not registered within autofac explicitly (like you can register object of type ISomeInterface and then resolve Owned without registering it explicitly). You can read more on this here: http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/ . Code of ViewRegistrationSource is presented here: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/ViewRegistrationSource.cs?r=8974cef867b5b2f2876a8c71037014424bd87aba As it is stated there its intention is to allow you to resolve WebViewPage, ViewPage, ViewMasterPage and ViewUserControl. You can define your views in cshtml files but you can as well define them as WebViewPage classes - they can be then shared across many assemblies - cshtml cannot. RazorGenerator tool can generate WebViewPage class for your cshtml view for you. Thanks to ViewRegistrationSource you can define in some assembly WebViewPage HomeView.cs and then without registering it with autofac just resolve it like context.Resolve() and return from action for instance.

Additional good reading on those topics: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Mvc3Integration.wiki?repo=wiki&r=7393a4178bea525f783cef91e206fbdc3921411a

Comment: Thank you for answering!  You helped a lot and provided great resources for me to continue my research! :)